# Can't make a while loop run for the entire list

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Im not sure how I can run the while loop until it has checked the entire list.

I have this but it just stops after it finds the first number.

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
target = 71
counter = 0
found = False
runtime = 0

while runtime < 13:
  while found == False:
    if numbers[counter] == target:
      found = True
    else:
      counter = counter + 1
  runtime = runtime + 1

if found == True:
  print("Found at position" , counter)
else:
  print("No match found")
```

Comment: what should the code do - please explain

Comment: I want the code to display Found at position 3 and Found at position 9 but right now it just says Found at position 3

Comment: Your outer loop (`while runtime < 13`) is continuing to iterate. However since you declare `found = True` upon first encountering `target` within `numbers`, your inner loop will not execute (since it is defined by `while found = False`. I would recommend considering something like `for i, n in enumerate(numbers)` - see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) - alongside a simple `if n == target` or something similar - if you intend to use loops to solve this issue.

Comment: No matter how many times you set `found` to `True`, your code only *checks* the value once, outside the loop. So of course it can only print one "found" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the code to display Found at position 3 and Found at position 9

Try (use [index()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/#:%7E:text=index()%20is%20an%20inbuilt,index%20where%20the%20element%20appears.&text=Parameters%20%3A,from%20where%20the%20search%20begins.) function)

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
offset = 0
while True:
  try:
    idx = numbers.index(71,offset)
    print(f'Found at position {idx}')
    offset = idx + 1
  except ValueError:
    break
```

output

```
Found at position 3
Found at position 9
```

Comment: I need it to output 

Found at position 3
Found at position 9

Comment: @mrKrauklis make sure you understand the index function and why ValueError exception is thrown. Look at other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

To find the positions use :

```
p =[i for i, j in enumerate(numbers) if j == target]
```

Then do necessary prints.